# How add each element of a list as an element of a new column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of list, like:

```
    X=[[1,1,2],[3,4,5],[8,1,9]]
```

and I have a dataframe with some columns, I will add a new column to my dataframe that each value of new column in each row is one of list of X, how can I do this?

to be more clear, for example, I have a dataframe in this image : [image]

and I have a list like X. then I want a new dataframe like: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3'},
                   'b': {0: 's', 1: 'n', 2: 'k'}})

X=[[1,1,2],[3,4,5],[8,1,9]]

df['new_col'] = X

df
```

output:

[image]